# Having some problems, not sure if it's even possible

Tags: html

I'm currently new(ish) at HTML. What I'm trying to do is Make a centered "Hello!" That has the font of Georgia and the font color of purple. This is what I have right now:

```
<div style="<font face="Georgia" color="purple"">
    <center><h1>Hello!</h1></center>
</div>
```

I'm not even sure if I'm doing it correctly, but right now it's hard to find an anwser without having to use CSS, and I have no idea how CSS works.

Comment: You **have** to use CSS - CSS: *Cascading Style Sheets* - HTML: *HyperText Markup Language* - HTML creates layouts, CSS styles said layout. Also Center is either deprecated or removed (can't remember which) so it will not work with newer browsers

Comment: Do learn CSS. Basically, you need to write the appropriate CSS instructions into the `style` attribute. `<font>` and `<center>` elements are obsolete. Don't even waste your time learning them.

Comment: The take a day and read up on CSS

Comment: ^^that or external style sheets

Comment: Your HTML, honestly, looks like it came out of a 1990s tutorial with some vague idea that CSS existed. You need to find a modern guide to HTML (MDN is a good starting point, W3Schools is not), and to learn CSS. The only element you have that should be in there is `<h1>`.

Comment: Take a look at this website:   https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy I wouldn't go for w3schools, full of bad practice and sometimes incorrect or vague code. (Just check the PHP section to find that out ..) - use MDN or w3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, CSS is required. HTML just builds the layout and framework of the page, while CSS styles it and makes it visually appealing / formatting how the page fits with everything. You should learn CSS. It's an excellent language that fits with HTML, and it will be very useful for later website development. Also, the tags `<font>` and `<center>` have been obsolete, so you shouldn't waste your time using them. You should look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5) for up to date HTML5 tags. Learning CSS will make this process a whole lot easier.

CSS:

```
.hello {
    color: purple;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<p class="hello">Hello!</p>
```

Comment: Just edited it now with a code example to do this, no problem

Comment: question about your edited comment, what does font-family: Georgia, Times, Times New Roman, serif; actually do? because it lists other fonts but not one singular, what happens when i want to use a singular font?

Comment: Ah, Thanks. if i wanted to use a different font, would I also have to list the fonts related to it i.e. the family the font I wanna use belongs to?

Comment: The browser checks the font in sequential order. If the font is available, it will use it and ignore the rest. So if you want to prioritize one, place it first.

Comment: mhm. Thanks for helping me. I'm very grateful. I'm new at html and have always wanted to code like the big boys, so this is a good start for me.